# LineageOS android build error at linux headers stage

Tags: android, build

I am trying to build LineageOS (CM replacement) on MAC OS sierra 10.12.2, however I cannot pass following section building kernel. I am not really sure if the problem is related to the SED errors or headers.

I just did as usual:

```
source build/envsetup.sh
brunch bullhead
```

...

error sample:

```
    warning: (ARCH_MSM) selects DEVFREQ_GOV_MSM_BW_HWMON which has unmet direct dependencies (PM_DEVFREQ && (ARCH_MSM_KRAIT || ARCH_MSM_BIMC_BWMON))
#
# configuration written to .config
#
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  INSTALL include/mtd (5 files)
  INSTALL include/drm (18 files)
  INSTALL include/asm-generic (35 files)
  INSTALL include/rdma (6 files)
  INSTALL include/media (20 files)
  INSTALL include/sound (18 files)
  INSTALL include/scsi/fc (4 files)
  INSTALL include/linux/../../../usr/include/linux/staging/android/uapi (2 files)
sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
make[3]: *** [/Volumes/android/system/out/target/product/bullhead/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/usr/include/drm/.install] Error 1
make[2]: *** [drm] Error 2
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: *** [/Volumes/android/system/out/target/product/bullhead/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/usr/include/sound/.install] Error 1
make[2]: *** [sound] Error 2
sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
  INSTALL include/scsi (5 files)
  INSTALL include/scsi/ufs (2 files)
make[4]: *** [/Volumes/android/system/out/target/product/bullhead/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/usr/include/linux/../../../usr/include/linux/staging/android/uapi/.install] Error 1
make[3]: *** [../../../drivers/staging/android/uapi] Error 2
make[2]: *** [linux] Error 2
sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
make[3]: *** [/Volumes/android/system/out/target/product/bullhead/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/usr/include/scsi/.install] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[4]: *** [/Volumes/android/system/out/target/product/bullhead/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/usr/include/scsi/ufs/.install] Error 1
make[3]: *** [ufs] Error 2
make[3]: *** [/Volumes/android/system/out/target/product/bullhead/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/usr/include/mtd/.install] Error 1
make[2]: *** [mtd] Error 2
make[3]: *** [/Volumes/android/system/out/target/product/bullhead/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/usr/include/rdma/.install] Error 1
make[2]: *** [rdma] Error 2
sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
make[3]: *** [/Volumes/android/system/out/target/product/bullhead/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/usr/include/media/.install] Error 1
make[3]: *** [/Volumes/android/system/out/target/product/bullhead/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/usr/include/asm-generic/.install] Error 1
make[2]: *** [media] Error 2
make[2]: *** [asm-generic] Error 2
make[4]: *** [/Volumes/android/system/out/target/product/bullhead/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/usr/include/scsi/fc/.install] Error 1
make[3]: *** [fc] Error 2
make[2]: *** [scsi] Error 2
make[1]: *** [headers_install] Error 2
make: *** [sub-make] Error 2
[  0% 135/42443] host Java: jarjar (/Volumes/android/syst...t/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/jarjar_intermediates/classes)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1

#### make failed to build some targets (01:11 (mm:ss)) ####
```

can someone help to point what to focus on in order pass further ?

Answer (score 0):

From a guide on how to build CyanogenMod on OSX:

We now need to create a couple of symlinks so that the gnu versions of 'sed' and 'find' are used rather than the osx provided versions :
Code:
ln -s /usr/local/bin/gfind /usr/local/bin/find && ln -s /usr/local/bin/gsed /usr/local/bin/sed && ln -s /usr/local/bin/gstat /usr/local/bin/stat

This worked for me, at least, on OSX 10.12.2